# Maven の pom ファイルでエラー: Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: java, maven, line

以下のGitHubのlinebotを作成しているのですが、Mavenのpomファイルにエラーが出て解決できません。

https://github.com/gishi-yama/linebot-java-handson/blob/master/doc/04.md

line-bot-clientのversionが1.20.0でエラーが出るので最新版の2.0.0に変更したのですが、添付画像のようにエラー `Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.linecorp.bot:line-bot-api-client:jar:1.20.0` が出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>linebot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>linebot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.linecorp.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-bot-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.linecorp.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-bot-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.linecorp.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-bot-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.linecorp.bot</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-bot-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: ちなみに`1.20.0`の場合だとどのようなエラーになったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

以下のartifact(ライブラリ)のバージョンが`1.20.0`のまま(`line-bot-api-client`とバージョン不一致)なのが原因と思います。

- `line-bot-servlet`
- `line-bot-spring-boot`

＃これらのPOMファイルを見ると、`line-bot-api-client`に依存しています。

(`line-bot-model`と合わせて)バージョンを`2.0.0`に合わせることでエラーを解消できると思います。

Answer (score 0):

何らかの理由で正常にファイルがダウンロードできていないことが起因している可能性があります。
ローカルリポジトリ(デフォルトでは `~/.m2/repository`)以下にある　 `com/linecorp/bot/line-bot-api-client` ディレクトリを削除して再実行してみて下さい。

(利用バージョン不統一は確かに修正されるべき問題でしょうが、今回のメッセージとは無関係かと思います。)